# Pure JS Ajax to jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make this:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
         document.getElementById("txtuser").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
   }
   xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajax.php?operation=get" + "&q=" + str, true);
   xmlhttp.send();
```

to jquery...

This is what I have:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: "operation=get" + "&q="+ str,
            success: function(){
                console.log('done');
            }
        });
    return false;
```

what I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: What does ajax.php look like? Are you getting any errors in console? Are you sure the request to ajax.php is successful?

Comment: console lets you look at the request, without feedback from the request itself  it could be a number of different issues

Answer (score 2):

I think your issue is with your data. jQuery is expecting the data to be JSON, so what you need is more like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: { operation: 'get', q: str},
        success: function(){
            console.log('done');
        }
 });
return false;
```

that should do what you want, jQuery will encode it into the URL for you automatically when the request is made.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are passing your data in the wrong way.. try with

```
data: { operation: 'get', q: str }
```